# Mutation & Query Props Not Passed to Component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

When my handler is called I get an error that the mutation is not a function. For some reason my mutation and query are not being attached to my component when I look at `this.props`.

ERROR:

```
RelationshipDropDown.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.deleteSystemDatasets is not a function
    at RelationshipDropDown.deleteHandler (RelationshipDropDown.js:58)
    at onClick (RelationshipDropDown.js:92) ...
```

I have tried multiple styles of syntax attempting to pass the mutation and query to the component and have used the style in other components with no error. Can someone explain why they are not being passed? Not sure what I am missing.

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//Import GraphQL
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo';


export class RelationshipDropDown extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {key:null, system:null};
    };
      deleteHandler() {
        if (this.state.key) {
            console.log(this.state.key, this.state.system)
            console.log(this.props)
            this.props.deleteSystemDatasets({
                variables:{key: this.state.key, datasets: [this.state.system]},
                refetchQueries: [{ query: this.props.getSystemDatasets , variables: {system:this.state.system} }]
            });
        console.log("Dataset " + this.state.key + "Deleted From " + this.state.system);
          }
       };

      handleChange(e){
        let obj = JSON.parse(e.target.value)
        console.log(e.target.value)
        console.log(this.props)
        this.setState({key: obj.key, system: obj.system});
      };

    render(){
        return (
          <div id="relationship-select">
            <select onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} className="select-menu" type="select">
              {this.props.dataArray}
            </select>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={() => this.deleteHandler()}>delete</button>
            <button>edit</button>
          </div>

        )
    }
}

export const GET_SYSTEM_DATASETS = gql`
  query getSystemDatasets($system: String!){
          System(name:$system){
               datasets{
                   name
               }
          }
      }
`;

export const DELETE_SYSTEM_DATASET_RELATIONSHIP = gql`
    mutation deleteSystemDatasets($systemKey: ID!, $datasetKeys: [ID!]!){
    deleteSystemDatasets(key:$systemKey, datasets: $datasetKeys)
    }
`;

const deleteSystemDatasets = graphql(DELETE_SYSTEM_DATASET_RELATIONSHIP, {name: "deleteSystemDatasets"});
const getSystemDatasets = graphql(GET_SYSTEM_DATASETS, {name: "getSystemDatasets"});

export default compose(deleteSystemDatasets, getSystemDatasets)(RelationshipDropDown);
```

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being a tedious error that I overlooked. When I did the default export, in the other file where I was rendering the component `<Component/>` I was importing the component as if I used a named export `export {Component}` via `import {Component} from '../path/to/component'`. All I had to do was remove the curly braces from my import statement and my props now contained my queries and mutations.